# How to configure an Ubuntu client with an APC Smart-UPS RT 5000 XL UPS

Tags: ubuntu, apc-smart-ups

I have an Ubuntu machine an APC Smart-UPS RT 5000 XL UPS.

I'd like to configure the UPS to send shutdown messages to the client when there is a power outage but I can't figure out how to install the software on Ubuntu.

Is there any Ubuntu compliant version of APC PowerChute? Should I use `apcupsd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `apcupsd` along with `gapcmon`

The full details can be found here:  [Linux: Configure and Control APC SmartUPS During a Power Failure](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-centos-rhel-install-apcups/)

Also, as Mario mentions in the comments, you may need to configure the ethernet cable as found here: [Further Configuration requirements](http://www.apcupsd.com/manual/#powerchute-network-shutdown-driver-pcnet)

Comment: I managed to get the UPS configured. The only thing I'd add to the post you linked to me is that you should configure the ethernet cable as reported here: http://www.apcupsd.com/manual/#powerchute-network-shutdown-driver-pcnet

Comment: Good deal..., I will update my answer to include your link and give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously necroposting, but I'd try my 2cents here anyways.
My advice is for those who ask how to install smth on Ubuntu.

There is another method to send shutdown messages without any dealings with Ubuntu by installing some app and configuring it.
APC does provide an image of completely tuned Ubuntu, ALREADY equipped with Web-interface. 
Through this interface you'll be able to configure a lot of options, including shutdown commands to be sent to other networking devices in a case of power failure.

Hence a name of this linux machine: APC Network Shutdown.
All you need - is to deploy this image or appliance somewhere in your network at any ESXi host.
You may download [PowerChute Network Shutdown v4.2 for Virtualization](http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/PowerChute-Network-Shutdown-v4-2-for-Virtualization/P-SFPCNS42-V) directly from APC site for free.